# Second Text Line Above The First Line

Tags: css, wordpress

[image]

I'm having an issue displaying a long title in a recent post widget of a wordpress site, because when the link is too long, it breakes to another line but this new line, is messing up with the first one, because the second line is above. I tried add this CSS line `line-height: 1.6em;` in `.widgettitle li` but didn't work and tried a couple of more classes that could possible be related by the name. Zero success on it, so what am I doing wrong?

I can only see the class that is applying to this box by expecting element, here's the URL http://experiencias.freeserver.me/. I do not see that class name on any of my index page nor head code.

```
.widgettitle {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#cc3234;
    border: 1px #D9D9D9 solid;
    font-size:20px;
    padding-left:5px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 5px;
}
    .textwidget {
    list-style-type: none;
    font: 14px/16px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding:5px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}
.widget {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding: 0 0 10px 10px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.widget .date {
    font-size:11px;
}
.widget h4 {
    font-weight:normal;
}
.widget .sub-menu {
    margin-left:10px;
}
.widget .sub-menu li{
    margin-left:5px;
}
.widget .menu-main-container li{
    list-style-type:square;
    margin-left:15px;
}
.recent-posts li, .tweet-list li {
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #555;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.recent-posts li:last-child {
    border-bottom:none !important;
    padding-bottom:none;
    margin-bottom:none;
}

.recent-posts h3 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.recent-posts h5 {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Show us the relevant HTML and CSS code, please.

Comment: Seems a line height question, but as Daniel pointed... Give us a fiddle or "real world" link, please. :)

Comment: Give `a` the code `line-height:1.6`. Problem solved!

Comment: @Chun and it worked, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving the `line-height` value to *.widgettitle li*, give it to *.widget_recent_entries li a*.

The problem was that you didn't declare the style to a selector with enough specificity. I suspect that the *a* tag previously inherited the `line-height` from *#sidebar-secondary li*.

Comment: To make your answer more complete, such "deepness" in CSS is _specificity_ : [link] http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity

Comment: @miguel-svq thanks for the tip. Will update with more appropriate terms.